# How to write a result in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I create a script that rescale path coordinates for each specific meter.
But I have a problem to save a result in CSV files.
First, I just run the script from cmd and store it in txt file and then transform in CSV file but this approach doesn't work when I want to read this result in another script I have an error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 42: invalid continuation byte
```

Then I try in the script write it in CSV file but I receive empty CSV file.
How can I save my result in CSV file than to read it in python as dataframe without an error?

My code looks next:

```
file = 'river_km_true_086_100_reference_trajectory.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ";")

f = open("new_coord.csv","w")
f.write("lon; lat\n")
f.close()

start_value = 0
stop_value = 1392 # Can be changed this value
step = 0.05 # in kilometers

for distance in np.arange(start_value, stop_value, step):
    try:
        x, y = getCoordinatesAt(distance)       
        print("distance, x, y: ", distance, x, y)       
        f.write(str(x) + ";" + str(y) + "\n")       

except:
    print("no value for distance ", distance)
```

Comment: I see several problems with your script. One obvious one is that you close your file (line 6) before the statement writing to it (line 15).

Comment: Can you please suggest to me how can I improve it?

Comment: @KaterynaLubyk: You are using `pd.read_csv(` why don't you use `pd.write_csv(`?

Comment: first, I read data from one CSV then do calculations and then want to store the output in new CSV file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but assuming that you get correct output on command line using your script, the following may work for you

```py
import csv
file = 'river_km_true_086_100_reference_trajectory.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ";")
start_value = 0
stop_value = 1392 # Can be changed this value
step = 0.05 # in kilometers

with open('new_coord.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    mywriter.writerow(["lon","lat"])
    for distance in np.arange(start_value, stop_value, step):
        try:
            x, y = getCoordinatesAt(distance)       
            print("distance, x, y: ", distance, x, y)       
            mywriter.writerow([str(x),str(y)])       

        except:
            print("no value for distance ", distance)
```